# Calculation of sound source position in 3d space

Tags: audio, vector, 3d, position, listener

I have a 3d vector for a listener position and a 3d vector for a sound source. I also have a 3d vector for the orientation of the listener. I am trying to find the NED (north, east, down) for the position of the source relative to the listener so I can play the sounds in the right speakers... I've made so research but I can't seem to find the necessary equations...
Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Ambisonics B-Format codec does what exactly what you're describing. However, although the specification of this codec is open, finding it is rather challenging due to it's unfortunate unpopularity.

The good news is, I've written a BSD open-source project called "Ambisonix" that details all the equations required to achieve up to 3rd order Ambisonics encoding and decoding. I've also added on some features such as distance encoding and Doppler effect which are not part of the original spec.

Check it out at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ambisonix

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to find exactly what you're looking for. Spatial location of sound sources in a 3D field is a very complex subject and depends on many factors (listener location, loudspeaker locations, source material). The closest to what you're describing is probably [Ambisonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambisonics), but this needs the listening setup to be Ambisonics too, which is not very common. If you're using something like Dolby Digital, I don't think they give out the equations, you need to license the algorithms or mix the source material with equipment which has the algorithms licensed and built in. However, systems such as Dolby are not really designed for precise sound source location in a 3D field - they're really just a spatial effect which gives the listener the feeling of a 3D sound field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract listener vector from sound vector then you can rotate through listener orientation vector. Now you can simple check if new vector is positive or negative on axes. For example vector [ 0, 10, -2] can be read as [0,+,-] and it means [central, up, back]. To use N-S W-E U-D directions just don't rotate vector after subtract.